# Retrofit error: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, retrofit, guava

The Java:

```
private void apiPasswordReset(final String msisdn) {
    showLoading();
    ListeningExecutorService service = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constants.API_THREADPOOL_SIZE));
    ListenableFuture<ResponseBase> response = service.submit(new Callable<ResponseBase>() {
        @Override
        public ResponseBase call() throws Exception {
            return webService.passwordReset(
                    Constants.RESPONSE_TYPE_APPLICATION_JSON,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.api_key),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.channel_id),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.app_id),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.base_url),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.base_url_port),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.api_version_string),
                    msisdn
            );
        }
    });

    Futures.addCallback(response, new FutureCallback<ResponseBase>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final ResponseBase result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Response Model:

```
public class ResponseBase {
    private boolean success;
    private String response_code;
    private String api_version;
    private String message;
    private String base_url;
}
```

The call:

```
@GET("/{endpoint}:{endpointPort}/api/{apiVersion}/users/{msisdn}/edit")
    ResponseBase passwordReset(
            @Header("Content-type") String contentType,
            @Header("x-api-key") String apiKey,
            @Header("channel-id") String channelId,
            @Header("app-id") String appId,
            @Path("endpoint") String endpoint,
            @Path("endpointPort") String endpointPort,
            @Path("apiVersion") String apiVersion,
            @Path("msisdn") String msisdn
    );
```

Request:

```
---> HTTP GET
x-api-key: 5ffc84c4-d1ad-29e8-4114-d84708bf96ac
channel-id: 1
app-id: android_001
Content-Type: application/json
---> END HTTP (no body)
```

Response:

```
<--- HTTP 200 (1013ms)
: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 217
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 08:31:40 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ikt5RWM4UFhDc1hrVytNRkNlc0QySVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiVmZ4KzF5bVdkY2xwbmJsaGZMbDZ1NldpNVp6bGsyemIyVGVKUzhcLzIrZDN3R3pGRWRVd0FWdnlnTjhaZCtyQ2JacTcybllvMW1ZOElaMU5TZUNpYUp3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI3YjBiZDM4MjM4OWMxMDRlOThiODU5ZDc1M2RhZTA5YmYyNDM0ZGE1NDQ0ZjQ0YWRmOTM5MjQ1NTI0ODkwNTAxIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 11-Apr-2016 10:31:40 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImsyVXcrRHpHY2FOakhZZDhIYjRnR1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiQTRcL2g0c1Ztdk9MbTl3MlNTblwvdHhicStrTHMzYlZmb3I2ZVc1NjBwNWIwYWQ5NjB2UXVyQzZBSUpLTzRcL0dta0gxUVR2ZnhaWnFoQStEUm93Q0lESlE9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQxYmY4NDk2OTgzNDZlZDVlMmM0MTUyMzMzN2ZhMmQ3YzY1ZWYyMTZlMDA4NWY3ZDc1ZTIzMTc1NzdmMzM3YjkifQ%3D%3D; expires=Mon, 11-Apr-2016 10:31:40 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
X-Android-Received-Millis: 1460363500117
X-Android-Response-Source: NETWORK 200
X-Android-Sent-Millis: 1460363499337
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
Version OK 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
{"success":true,"response_code":"OK","api_version":1,"message":"PASSWORD RESET NOTIFICATION SENT SUCCESSFULLY","error":[],"base_url":"http:\/\/apiserver.com","data":[]}
```

The response data seems to fit the model. When I run this call with postman it returns valid json aswell. I have commented out all fields in the model and still get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Versions:
Android studio 2.0
Gradle 2.0
Retrofit 1.9.0
Guava 19.0

---

### FIX:

Due to my own stupidity :|
Server was including text ouside the object in the response that should be part of the header. Thanks for the assist guys!

Postman response:

```
Version OK 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14
{"success":true,"response_code":"OK","api_version":1,"message":"PASSWORD RESET NOTIFICATION SENT SUCCESSFULLY","error":[],"base_url":"http:\/\/apiserver.com","data":[]}
```

Comment: I think you are receiving json as array and trying to store as object. That could be your issue.

Comment: Should the error not then be Expected OBJECT but received ARRAY?

Comment: Is the requests and the response from postman or Retrofit? Are you sure the server response is the same when you make the postman request. I usually get the "but was STRING" part when the server returns an 400 error like "invalid input". I'd suggest to add logging to your Retrofit instance.

Comment: That was my retrofit response, my logging is set to .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)